# Not able to understand the syntax href =\"\

Tags: python-3.x, youtube

I am trying to write a simple python script to search and download youtube video using youtube-dl. I have come across the following [code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/873060/Python-Search-Youtube-for-Video) which search for the  video id. I am not able to understand the following line:

```
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
```

A youtube video link is like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJGkm0UwNRk
does the use of href =\"\ means to skip the https://www.youtube.com part and move to the */watch?v=<11digit id>* or something else.

Code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input()})
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
```

Comment: @KenWhite I know what href is but I am confused with the syntax href =\"\ cause a youtube link normally goes like   ' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJGkm0UwNRk'. Does using href =\"\ mean to skip the https://www.youtube.com part or something else.

Comment: You should edit your question then, to make it clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for [regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re).

And this is the explanation from [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JDzl9p/1):

```
"href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})"g

href= matches the characters href= literally (case sensitive)
\" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
watch matches the characters watch literally (case sensitive)
\? matches the character ? literally (case sensitive)
v= matches the characters v= literally (case sensitive)

1st Capturing Group (.{11})
    .{11} matches any character (except for line terminators)
    {11} Quantifier — Matches exactly 11 times
```